# Julia char array to string

Tags: arrays, string, type-conversion, julia

This seems like a really obvious thing to do, but I couldn't find a solution. I tried:

```
convert(String, array)
# -> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Char,1} to an object of type String
```

and

```
string(array)
# -> "['U']"
```

Obviously none achieve what I want to achieve.

---

My whole code looks like this:

```
function to_rna(dna)
    assignments = Dict('G' => 'C', 'C' => 'G', 'T' => 'A', 'A' => 'U')
    res = Char[length(dna)]
    for i in 1:length(dna)
        res[i] = assignments[dna[i]]
    end
    return string(res)
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the actual `String` constructor:

```
julia> String(['a', 'b', 'c'])
"abc"
```

Comment: That's almost perfect (and as simple as I would've hoped), but it doesn't work for an empty array (yields in `"\0"`)

Comment: `res = Vector{Char}(undef,length(dna))` should be used to initialize `res` or just write `res = map(i -> assignments[i], dna)`.